# Polymorphism thing about a member variable

Tags: c#, .net, polymorphism, overriding

I always think I know the Polymorphism until I meet below example.

I have two classes, Father and Son. Code as follows:

Father:

```
public class Father
{
    public String name = "father";
    public virtual void dosth()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
}
```

Son:

```
public class Son : Father
{
     public String name = "son";
     public override void dosth()
     {
          Console.WriteLine(name);
     }
}
```

And I Call them:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Father p = new Son();
    Console.WriteLine(p.GetType()); //print son
    p.dosth();                      //print son
    Console.WriteLine(p.name);      //print father
}
```

As I think, variable p points to a son object, so first, Console will print "Son" Type. And I'm right.

Then `p.dosth()` will call the son's `dosth()`, So it will print "son". And I'm right again.

Last, `p.name` should be "son", too. But, this time, I'm wrong. It prints "father".

I can't understand that p variable's type is son, why it still use the father's member?

Comment: Methods are overridden, variables are not but rather are "hidden". The p variable is a Father variable, and so that is the variable that is displayed.

Comment: Why do you define name 2nd time in son? Normally the son should inherit the name from its father if you want to demonstrate some polymorphic scenario. This is confusing no matter of the language used. Also, how is this Java?